# Updating a table based on aggregation results from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

The idea for this is that I am trying to update salaries of Instructors differently based on if they're mentoring Freshman, Sophomores, Juniors, or Seniors.  Only the highest applicable raise should be applied, which I have gathered is covered by the fact that `case` statements are evaluated sequentially.

I am using `select` statements to count if there are any occurrences where an instructor mentors a certain classification of students, and then if there are, applying the applicable raise.

```
update Instructor i
set i.Salary = (
case 
when (0 < (select count(*) from Student s where s.Classification = "Senior" 
    and i.InstructorID = s.MentorID)) then i.Salary * 1.1
when (0 < (select count(*) from Student s where s.Classification = "Junior" 
    and i.InstructorID = s.MentorID)) then i.Salary * 1.08
when (0 < (select count(*) from Student s where s.Classification = "Sohpomore" 
    and i.InstructorID = s.MentorID)) then i.Salary * 1.06
when (0 < (select count(*) from Student s where s.Classification = "Freshman" 
    and i.InstructorID = s.MentorID)) then i.Salary * 1.04
else i.Salary
end);
```

This query I wrote doesn't execute.  Is it valid syntax to put the `select` statements inside the `when` as a comparison?  If so, what is the issue with the above code?  Or do I have to move these to a `where` statement with some control flow logic?  I have a feeling this is inefficient due to the large number of `select` statements.

EDIT:  Here is some sample data and the expected output:

```
Student: MentorID Classification
         100      Sophomore
         101      Junior
         102      Senior
         101      Senior

Instructor: InstructorID Salary
            100          100000 
            101          50000 
            102          80000 
            103          100000
```

After Update

```
Instructor: InstructorID Salary
            100          106000 //*1.06 because mentee is a sophomore
            101          55000  //*1.1 because highest mentee is senior
            102          88000  //*1.1 because mentee is a senior
            103          100000 //No change because no mentees
```

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data and your expected results before/after so someone could try to recreate the issure?

Comment: Misunderstood you originally, some sample data has been added!

Comment: I believe your problem is the parentheses, as I got an error until I removed them. Regardless, I have offered what is (hopefully) a bit more of an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that it may be inefficient to run several select statements. You can eliminate that. Before doing any update, I think we can agree we need at least the following:

- How many students of each classification does each instructor mentor?

Let's consider the following sample data set for instructors and students:

```
| instructorID | name | salary |
+--------------+------+--------+
|       1      | Adam |    1   |
|       2      | Sam  |    1   |
|       3      | John |    1   |
|       4      | Jane |    1   |

| studentID | classification | mentorID |
+-----------+----------------+----------+
|    1      |   Senior       |    1     |
|    2      |   Junior       |    1     |
|    3      |   Sophomore    |    2     |
|    4      |   Freshman     |    2     |
|    5      |   Senior       |    1     |
|    6      |   Freshman     |    3     |
|    7      |   Sophomore    |    1     |
```

In this case, Adam teaches senior's so his salary should go to 1.1. John teaches at most Sophomore so his salary will be 1.06. Sam teaches at most a freshman, so his salary will be 1.04 and Jane teaches no one so her salary should remain 1 at the end.

We can find the number of students per instructor using the following aggregation:

```
SELECT i.instructorID,
   SUM(s.classification = 'Senior') AS numSeniors,
   SUM(s.classification = 'Junior') AS numJuniors,
   SUM(s.classification = 'Sophomore') AS numSophomores,
   SUM(s.classification = 'Freshman') AS numFreshmen
FROM instructor i
LEFT JOIN student s ON s.mentorID = i.instructorID
GROUP BY i.instructorID;
```

You can use this as a `JOIN` in an update statement to set the values using a case statement:

```
UPDATE instructor i
JOIN (mySubquery) tmp ON tmp.instructorID = i.instructorID
SET i.salary = 
   CASE WHEN tmp.numSeniors > 0 THEN (i.salary * 1.1)
   WHEN tmp.numJuniors > 0 THEN (i.salary * 1.08)
   WHEN tmp.numSophomores > 0 THEN (i.salary * 1.06)
   WHEN tmp.numFreshmen > 0 THEN (i.salary * 1.04)
   ELSE i.salary END;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ee2e/1) example.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I always get stuck on making a bunch of select statements, this definitely helps

Comment: The SUM(condition) is a new trick that I just learned a few weeks ago. It's very helpful.